# Websites not loading properly in Chrome - Windows 10 Lenovo Yoga

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Yoga 910 running Windows 10 which is up to date. In Chrome, on some websites where they is an overlay panel, the rendering happens in stages with a lot of flickering (see the attached gif). This is especially an issue on websites like Facebook which opens up images in a panel.

[image: GIF of issue]

My graphics card is Intel HD Graphics 620 and as per Device Manager, I have latest driver. I have also verified that it's not because of any extensions as the same thing happens in Incognito Mode.

Edit:
Hardware acceleration is disabled. This issue does not happen on Firefox.

Any suggestions on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Is that only for Chrome? Run chrome with command: `chrome.exe --disable-dwm-composition --disable-gpu`

Comment: Just installed and tried with Firefox. Don't see the same issue. Running Chrome with above command doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Hardware acceleration is already disabled, if that's what `disable-gpu` does.